# InlineUIContainer delete event in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, inlineuicontainer

Is there a way, to get notified when an `InlineUIContainer` gets deleted in a `RichTextBox`? Currently I am using the `Unload` event, which is a problem because the event is also called when I switch between tabs.

My code:

Creating the `InlineUIContainer`:

```
InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(presenter) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.TextBottom };
container.Tag = new TagTextBoxObject(Id, InputText);
container.Unloaded += presenter_Unloaded;
```

The event, which should not get fired on switching tabs:

```
void presenter_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(
        (Action)delegate()
        {
            TagTextBoxObject item = (TagTextBoxObject)(sender as InlineUIContainer).Tag;

            if (newItems.ContainsKey(item.Id))
            {
                newItems.Remove(item.Id);
            }

            if (!deletedItems.ContainsKey(item.Id))
            {
                deletedItems.Add(item.Id, item.Text);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: The event is called because the previously selected page was unloaded. What is the purpose to be noticed when an InlineUIContainer gets deleted?

Comment: I've developed a Tag based tagbox, and if i delete a tag via backspace, i delete the tag also from the database. But now the data were deleted without using backspace :)

Comment: You should put your solution in the answer box and accept it, and not edit it into the question, otherwise the question stays in the "unsolved" queue.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 If you're going to bump a months-old question, you should be fixing **everything** that can be fixed. There were many typos and other issues in the question that you could have fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, look wether the parent is loaded:

```
    void presenter_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent != null && this.Parent is FrameworkElement)
        {
            if ((this.VisualParent as FrameworkElement).IsLoaded)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    (Action)delegate()
                    {
                        TagTextBoxObject item = (TagTextBoxObject)(sender as InlineUIContainer).Tag;

                        if (newItems.ContainsKey(item.Id))
                        {
                            newItems.Remove(item.Id);
                        }

                        if (!deletedItems.ContainsKey(item.Id))
                        {
                            deletedItems.Add(item.Id, item.Text);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe from the Unload event when the `TabControl.SelectionChanged` is fired. And subscribe again when the specific tab is selected.

But I think that better way is to create a custom control which will hosts a TextBox and an ItemsControl and do not use RichTextBox.

Comment: Thank you for your unswer, but i found a more handy solution, look at my **EDIT 2**. But you gave me the hint :)